# Divisão exata (inteira)

Tags: java, android

Preciso fazer uma divisão mas que ela dê sempre resto zero, divisão exata.
Acho que estou pecando na condição.

```
Random Number;
int Rnumber1;
int Rnumber2;
RandomValor1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtValor1);
RandomValor2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtValor2);

Number = new Random();
Rnumber1 = Number.nextInt(20);
Rnumber2 = Number.nextInt(10);


while (Rnumber1/Rnumber2==0 ) {

    Rnumber1 = Number.nextInt(20);
    Rnumber2 = Number.nextInt(10);


}

RandomValor1.setText(Integer.toString(Rnumber1));
RandomValor2.setText(Integer.toString(Rnumber2));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para obter o resto da divisão de dois números utilize o operador modulo `%`. Veja o seguinte código:

```
while(valor1 % valor2 != 0)
```

A condição a cima quer dizer que enquanto o resto da divisão do `valor1` pelo `valor2` for diferente de zero, faça algo.

Adaptação para seu código:

```
while (Rnumber1 % Rnumber2 != 0) {

    Rnumber1 = Number.nextInt(20);
    Rnumber2 = Number.nextInt(10);
}
```

Para garantir que `Rnumber1` é maior ou igual a `Rnumber2` altera a condição assim:

```
while (Rnumber1 < Rnumber2 || Rnumber1 % Rnumber2 != 0) {

    Rnumber1 = Number.nextInt(20);
    Rnumber2 = Number.nextInt(10);
}
```

---

Pelo que percebo você tem os seguintes requisitos:

1. O divisor deve ser um número entre 1 e 10
2. O dividendo deve ser um número <= a 20 e >= ao divisor.

O método `Number.nextInt(x)` gera números entre `0` e `x-1`, assim, para garantir o primeiro requisito o código será assim:

```
Rnumber2 = Number.nextInt(10) + 1;
```

Para garantir o seguinte requisito faremos assim:

```
R.number1 = Number.nextInt(21 - Rnumber2) + Rnumber2;
```

O código alterado será assim:

```
Random Number;
int Rnumber1;
int Rnumber2;

Number = new Random();
RandomValor1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtValor1);
RandomValor2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TxtValor2);

do {
    Rnumber2 = Number.nextInt(10) + 1;
    Rnumber1 = Number.nextInt(20 - Rnumber2 + 1) + Rnumber2;
}while (Rnumber1 % Rnumber2 != 0)

RandomValor1.setText(Integer.toString(Rnumber1));
RandomValor2.setText(Integer.toString(Rnumber2));
```

Comment: ramaral é o seguinte, estou fazendo um jogo de cálculo para criança. Preciso que a operação de divisão  seja sempre uma divisão exata, tipo 2/2 6/3 etc... estou pecando nisso...  preciso que seja exibida somente se tiver esse critério

Comment: while (Rnumber1 % Rnumber2 == 0 && Rnumber1>Rnumber2) {

            Rnumber1 = Number.nextInt(20);
            Rnumber2 = Number.nextInt(10);
            RandomValor1.setText(Integer.toString(Rnumber1));
            RandomValor2.setText(Integer.toString(Rnumber2));

        }

Comment: Já fez a alteração que eu indiquei?

Comment: while (Rnumber1 % Rnumber2 != 0 && Rnumber1 >= Rnumber2) {
            Rnumber1 = Number.nextInt(20);
            Rnumber2 = Number.nextInt(10);

            RandomValor1.setText(Integer.toString(Rnumber1));
            RandomValor2.setText(Integer.toString(Rnumber2));
}  Não ta funcionando...

Comment: @seamusd *"esse operador só deve ser usado para números inteiros."* Isso não é [verdade](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html)

Comment: Troque as condições: `while (Rnumber1 >= Rnumber2 && Rnumber1 % Rnumber2 != 0)`

Comment: @ramaral na minha concepção, só seria possível para números inteiros. Mas se você está dizendo. Abs. +1 pela resposta.

Comment: @seamusd Não sou eu que digo, são as [especificações do java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3).

Comment: to apanhando feio...  mesmo com essa condição, ele gera um valor menor que o segundo.  Minha dúvida, com while nessa condição que está ele vai ficar repetindo até conseguir as duas condições correto? somente depois ele da sequencia no código?

Comment: // Number = new Random();
        Rnumber1 = Number.nextInt(20);
        Rnumber2 = Number.nextInt(10);

        while (Rnumber1 >= Rnumber2 && Rnumber1 % Rnumber2 != 0) {
            Rnumber1 = Number.nextInt(20);
            Rnumber2 = Number.nextInt(10);

        }

        RandomValor1.setText(Integer.toString(Rnumber1));
        RandomValor2.setText(Integer.toString(Rnumber2));//   esse é o meu botão.

Comment: Sim a ideia é essa. `Troque Rnumber1 >= Rnumber2` por `Rnumber1 < Rnumber2`. Não tinha reparado que a condição estava errada.

Comment: Rnumber1 < Rnumber2 && Rnumber1 % Rnumber2 != 0          mesmo assim ele continua gerando operação tipo 13/4  0/5    não consigo entender... sera que devo colocar um while dentro do outro tipo assim?

Comment: Vou editar a resposta com uma solução "melhor".

Comment: ramaral, não ta funcionando.  com essa mudança que fez, ele não verifica se é uma divisão exata... tem que ter um validar dos valores resultados senão da errado.  Obrigado pela ajuda, vou tentar mais por aqui, qd resolver posto a solução.

Comment: Tem razão, peço desculpa, falta verificar a divisão.

Comment: Resolvido... não era &&   e sim ||  ... agora esta redondo... Obrigado pela ajuda.                                                                                                           Resultado final                                                                                         while ((Rnumber1 < Rnumber2) || (Rnumber1 % Rnumber2 != 0))